# After final submission of a request i get null responses in the success page

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Lets Assume I’m Filling up some form to order a product.All are simple jsp files. So before submitting the page, a review page comes up where all the prices , add-on details are shown.

When I submit this page I get a order success page where I need to get the same price details. My problem is somehow the values that comes up during the review page gets all null values after submission thus getting different prices in the order page. I could not post the code side as it’s gigantic.

Could I have some theoretic responses please.

This is the piece of code from where the prices gets rendered in the review and success page.

id="oneTimeCost" class="one-order one-ordercost" < value="{not empty check.newPhone.redeemCharge ? check.newPhone.redeemCharge : '#OneTimeCost#

During the review page the values are
check.newPhone.redeemCharge  = no value due to which the condition becomes as false and #OneTimeCost# value is rendered which is fine.

When I submit the order. the values are
check.newPhone.redeemCharge = 0 due to which the conditions becomes true and  check.newPhone.redeemCharge value is printed which is 0. It should be the same as the value of  '#OneTimeCost#'.

Issue 1: if you say put #OneTimeCost# instead of check.newPhone.redeemCharge 
This won't work as in the browser the  "#OneTimeCost# " same thing gets printed.

Issue 2: If you say , now the two variables are yielding the same value why put it in a condition.
Fine. I just print the value #OneTimeCost#  with no condition. Guess what same thing happens as it was in issue 1, and if I use the check.newPhone.redeemCharge value it gives me 0

Comment: Please see [ask], especially where it talks about a [mcve]. The idea is you tell us what you want to do, show what you tried and what research you've done, and show what results you get.

Comment: Can you show us what you done in your jsp code

Comment: If the code is gigantic, then write some other, minimal code reproducing only the problem you're having, and post that code.

Comment: You may need to save the data into a session.

Comment: I have added the piece of code. Sessions is not helping in this case. Just a thought if we can save a session between a review and confirm page the user can just go back to the review page after submitting the order which should not be the case